# Magento XML $this->getChildHtml() necessary?

Tags: xml, magento, php

I have edited the following file, to move the newsletter to the footer instead of the sidebar

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/newsletter.xml
```

I changed the following code:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

to:

```
<reference name="footer">
```

Why did I not need to add

```
$this->getChildHtml('newsletter')
```

or similar to footer.phtml?
I am unsure when to use getChildHtml() and when not to.
Are all the steps necessary in Exercise#2 of [this article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts) ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look at `page/html/footer.phtml`, which is the footer block's template

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
        <p class="bugs"><?php echo $this->__('Help Us to Keep Magento Healthy') ?> - <a href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking" onclick="this.target='_blank'"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Report All Bugs') ?></strong></a> <?php echo $this->__('(ver. %s)', Mage::getVersion()) ?></p>
        <address><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that they've used the following PHP to output the child blocks

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

When `getChildHtml` is called without a parameter, it will output **any** block that's been added.  That's why you didn't need to include your own call to `$this->getChildHtml('newsletter')`

Comment: How can I move the newsletter using local.xml instead of changing newsletter.xml?